# How to distribute a loop to run one iteration per core

Tags: shell, loops, parallel-processing

I am running a semi-large loop in a shell script on a server with 30 cores. It looks like the one below. I would like to distribute this loop to run one iteration per core:

python sim_fine.py model1 weak a true --> on core 1, 
python sim_fine.py model1 weak b true --> on core 2 
etc...

I would like to utilize 20 of the 30 cores for his process. Basically what I want is the iteration not to wait for the previous to finish, before starting the next one. This may only happen 20 times of course. I have been looking around the internet but could not find any help on this topic.

```
for m in model1 model2;
    do
    for s in weak strong;
        do
        for opt_dict in a b c d;
            do
                python sim_fine.py $m $s $opt_dict true
            done
        done
    done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use **GNU Parallel** for that although it seems to only generate 16 jobs not the 20 you indicate:

```
parallel --dry-run python sim.py ::: model{1,2} ::: weak strong ::: {a..d}
```

**Sample Output**

```
python sim.py model1 weak a
python sim.py model1 weak b
python sim.py model1 weak c
python sim.py model1 weak d
python sim.py model1 strong a
python sim.py model1 strong b
python sim.py model1 strong c
python sim.py model1 strong d
python sim.py model2 weak a
python sim.py model2 weak b
python sim.py model2 weak c
python sim.py model2 weak d
python sim.py model2 strong a
python sim.py model2 strong b
python sim.py model2 strong c
python sim.py model2 strong d
```

If that looks good, run it in earnest without `--dry-run`. If you really want to limit the number of parallel jobs to 20, use:

```
parallel -j 20 ...
```

There are many, many very flexible options for handling logging, reporting and error-handling if you run `man parallel`.

I was being somewhat lazy/concise with the parameter handling, you could be more explicit with:

```
parallel --dry-run python sim.py {1} something {2} somethingelse {3} true ::: model{1,2} ::: weak strong ::: {a..d}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark!! Yes, I shortened the loop so that it is less confusing and then I managed to make below 20 iterations. My bad! When I run this then I will now get an error saying the following: "/bin/bash: sim.py: Permission denied". Any idea why this occurs?

Comment: Sorry, I copied badly, you want `sim_fine.py`

Comment: Ohh it is not due to the name error. Could it be due to missing "$".

Comment: I solved the issues. It was due to some restrictions on my local server. Thank you again! I appreciate your help!